# Probability Problem with 10 players, Bob and a friend being on a team

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Please check my work.

Out of 10 players including Bob and his two best friends a team of 5 players will be formed. What is the likelihood of Bob making the team with at most one of his friends?

Total Possible Teams

$$\binom{10}{5} = 252$$

Bob with at least one other friend.

$$\binom{8}{3} = 56$$

Divide total possibilities with possibilities of teams with Bob and his friend.

$$\frac{\mbox{Combinations}}{\mbox{Total Possibilities}} = \frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: I would have thought  Bob and no friends was ${7 \choose 4}$, while Bob and two friends was ${7 \choose 2}$, and Bob and exactly one friend was ${2 \choose 1}{7\choose 3}$

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, this wasn't a statement, I'm trying to get my work checked.

Comment: Would this mean that Bob has a 50 percent chance of being on a team with one of his friends?

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed $$\binom{10}{5}$$ ways to form a team of five players from among the ten people.

If Bob is selected to be on the team, there are $$\binom{7}{4}$$ ways to select four teammates for Bob from among the seven people who are not his friends.

If Bob is selected to be on the team, there are $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{7}{3}$$ ways to select exactly one of his two friends and three of the other seven people to be on Bob's team.

Hence, the probability that Bob makes the team with at most one of his  friends is
$$\frac{\dbinom{7}{4} + \dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{7}{3}}{\dbinom{10}{5}}$$

Note that the complementary event is that either Bob is not selected for the team, which can occur in $$\binom{9}{5}$$ ways since five of the other nine people must be selected to be on the team, or Bob and both his friends are selected, which can occur in $$\binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{2}$$ ways since both his friends and two of the other seven people must be selected to be on Bob's team.  Hence, the probability that Bob makes the team with at most one of his friends is $$1 - \frac{\dbinom{9}{5} + \dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{7}{2}}{\dbinom{10}{5}}$$

**Addendum:**  In the comments, Graham Kemp suggested another method.  There are
$$\binom{9}{4}$$
teams which could include Bob since we must choose four of the other nine people to be his teammates.  We know that
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{2}$$
include both his friends.  Therefore, the number of teams which include at most one of his friends is
$$\binom{9}{4} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{2}$$
Consequently, the probability that Bob makes the team with at most one of his friends is
$$\frac{\dbinom{9}{4} - \dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{7}{2}}{\dbinom{10}{5}}$$

Comment: Alternatively, there are $\binom 94$ teams of 5 that contain Bob, and $\binom 72$ of those contain both from his 2 friends, so...

Comment: @GrahamKemp  That is a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your computation of total ways of forming the teams is correct, but that for favorable ways is not.

When learning a particular type of problem, it is best to avoid shortcuts and use a standard method.

The people involved are Bob (B), friend $F_1$, friend $F_2, 7\;$ others $\;(O)$

If *exactly* one friend is to be on the team along with Bob, **[see PS]** the selections which are "good" are $B,F_1,3O's\;$ and $B,F_2,3O's\;$

So using the formula for selection without replacement, you should be able to solve it.

Later on, when you gain more experience, you can think of how the process can be shortened.

**PS** $\;\;$Your header and body are contradictory. Header states "... Bob and a friend on the team..." whereas body states "... Bob and *at most* one of his friends.."

Taking the interpretation of the header to imply *exactly* one friend on the team along with Bob, the baby steps would be $\dfrac{\binom11\binom11\binom73 + \binom11\binom11\binom73}{\binom{12}5} = \dfrac5{18}$

It can, of course be simplified to $\dfrac{\binom21\binom73}{\binom{12}5}$

Comment: I wasn't taught how to use a "standard" method, how they're teaching us is, well how to use permutations and our "logical understanding." Reworking the problem, I'm looking at Bob with friend 1 and 3 others $$\binom{8}{3} = 56$$ Bob with friend 2 and 3 others $$\binom{8}{3} = 56$$, and then bob with both friends and 2 others $$\binom{7}{2} = 21$$. I Added these total number of combinations up, and divided by total possibilities and got an answer of about 0.52 percent. Does that sound about right?

Comment: No; that is over counting  The event of "Bob, friend 1, and *3 from 8* others" includes friend-2 among those others.  The count for "Bob, friend-1, and *3 from the 7* unfriends" is $\binom 7 3$.  @JoseGarcia

Comment: **PS** Also, you are counting teams with Bob and *at least* one of his friends, but you seek to count teams with Bob and *at most* one from them. @JoseGarcia  Teams to Count: Bob, 1 from 2 friends, & 3 from 7 unfriends, OR Bob, 0 from 2 friends, & 4 from 7 unfriends

Comment: @GrahamKemp: The header and body don't match exactly, so now I have worked out the problem for **exactly** one friend being on the team along with Bob

Comment: @JoseGarcia: You are now having answers for a number of interpretations of your question, due to the difference in wording between the header and the body. Anyway, I hope you understand that all of them follow the *logical* formulas for selection without replacement.